# How can I test with multiple versions of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, multiple-versions

How can I test my website in multiple versions of firefox?
I have v2 installed. Now no matter where or how many times I install FF3, it always executes ff2..

I checked the interweb and it seems there used to be a MultiFireFox tool that could run several versions. It was for apple and I'm on windows. Furthermore all the links to it are dead.
I also found an option I could add to the executable. But since I cannot start FF3 to begin with, I reckon this doesn't make much sence.

Something like [MultipleIE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) would be great.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is set up two profiles, one for Firefox3 and on for Firefox 2. It's a pretty simple process; I've got them both running and I love it!

[Here's one way to set up two profiles](http://blog.codefront.net/2007/08/20/how-to-have-firefox-3-and-firefox-2-running-at-the-same-time/)

Comment: it was the combination of the profilemanager (I had found that already) and the -no-remote option :) Thx

Answer (score 9):

Try out [Firefox portable](http://portableapps.com/news/2008-12-16_-_firefox_portable_3.0.5)... each version one folder.

Answer (score 3):

You might try setting up a few virtual machines, and installing different browser versions on each.

Ex:

- VM1 - IE6, FF1
- VM2 - IE7, FF2
- VM3 - IE8B, FF3

etc.

Comment: That's a bit far fetched. But let's call it plan B

Comment: I agree. You definitely don't need to go down this route.

Comment: Agreed, sounds like overkill to me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-no-remote` to avoid just telling the running instance to open a new window.

Usually you'll want to combine that with `-P` to run both instances with different profiles.

Just check the [available command line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options).

Answer (score 0):

The general case of running two separate Firefox processes is described in [this Mozillazine article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile).  There's also [this article which covers different versions specifically](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Testing_pre-release_versions).

To make life easier I recommend downloading the nightly builds in zip format rather than trying to run the installers (eg. [here's the current 2.0 trunk](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla1.8/)).

Comment: how exactly would that make life easier?

Comment: If you use the installers they will uninstall older versions automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to check standalone pages (i.e not part of a flow), you can test your pages online with Browsershots - http://browsershots.org/

Browsershots is a free open-source online service that takes a URL & as per your choosing, checks it on a variety of browsers, different versions of each and on different Operating systems.

Comment: Yes, this service has been suggested to me before. Have you ever actually tried it? Let's just say there are not enough hours in a work day to do the check more then twice ;)